# Troubles with Perl and tar

Tags: perl, backup, tar

I'm writing this backup script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use DBI;

my $destdir       = "/mnt/backup";
my $tmpdir        = "/mnt/backup/tmp";
my $mysqlpassword = "";

my %backup = (
    '/home' => [
        'path/to/exclude/from/backup/*',
    ],
    '/etc',
);

my $now = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%s", localtime);
my $tmpbdir = "$tmpdir/backup_$now";

sub printlog
{
    print "[", strftime("%D %T", localtime), "] $_[0]\n";
}

sub backup
{
    foreach my $dir (keys %backup) {
        printlog "Backing up $dir...";
        my $excludes = "";
        if ($#{$backup{$dir}}+1 > 0) {
            for my $i (0 .. $#{$backup{$dir}}) {
                $excludes = "--exclude $dir/$backup{$dir}[$i] ";
            }
            $excludes =~ s/\s$//;
        }
        system("tar -cJf $excludes $tmpbdir/$dir.xz $dir");
        printlog "$dir backup complete.";
    }
}

sub backup_mysql
{
    printlog "Backing up MySQL...";
    mkdir("$tmpbdir/mysql");
    my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:information_schema', 'root', $mysqlpassword, {'RaiseError' => 1});
    if ($dbh) {
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA'); $sth->execute;
        while (my @databases = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
            system("mysqldump --opt --single-transaction --user=root --password=$mysqlpassword $databases[0] > $tmpbdir/mysql/$databases[0].sql");
        }
        system("tar -cjf $tmpbdir/mysql.xz $tmpbdir/mysql");
        system("rm -rf $tmpbdir/mysql");
        printlog "MySQL backup complete.";
    } else {
        print "Unable to connect to MySQL server.\n$DBI::errstr\n";
    }
}

sub archive
{
    printlog "Archiving...";
    system("tar -cf $destdir/backup_$now.tar $tmpbdir/*");
    system("rm -rf $tmpbdir");
    printlog "Backup complete in $destdir/backup_$now.tar";
}

if ($> != 0) {
    die "You must run this script as root.\n";
}

printlog "Backup starts.";
mkdir($tmpbdir);

&backup;
&backup_mysql;
&archive;
```

But when I run the script, the /home backup fails. This is the output of the script.

```
[...]
[01/03/12 03:00:03] Backing up /home...
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /mnt/backup/tmp/backup_2012-01-03-1325556001//home.xz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: /home/minecraft/world/region/r.-1.1.mcr: file changed as we read it
tar: /home/minecraft/world: file changed as we read it
tar: /home/webserver/ubuntubarsport/log/access_log: file changed as we read it
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
[...]
```

I don't know the reason of `tar: /mnt/backup/tmp/backup_2012-01-03-1325556001//home.xz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`. What am I doing wrong? The /etc backup works fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you print the command that's being executed, just before system() add - print "executing tar -cJf $excludes $tmpbdir/$dir.xz $dir\n"; and show what is printed?

Comment: `executing tar -cJf --exclude /home/webserver/ubuntubarsport/www/minecraft/* /mnt/backup/tmp/backup_2012-01-03-1325581860//home.xz /home` and `executing tar -cJf  /mnt/backup/tmp/backup_2012-01-03-1325581860//etc.xz /etc` for /etc, which works.

I really don't know why there is a trailing slash in $tmpbdir as I defined it as `$tmpbdir = "$tmpdir/backup_$now"`

Comment: But /etc and /home have a starting slash in the path :D Found the bug. I hope.

Comment: It continues returning me `tar: /mnt/backup/tmp/backup_2012-01-03-1325556001/home.xz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory` :\

Comment: Nope.
With `tar --ignore-failed-read $excludes -PcJf $tmpbdir$dir.xz $dir` does not return that error anymore, but there are all the files I excluded.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a directory in which you are trying to create a backup tarball. Add

```
system("mkdir -p $tmpbdir");
```

to the beginning of backup().

**EDIT**:

Also the backup tarball should be on the command line right after -f, so instead of

```
system("tar -cJf $excludes $tmpbdir/$dir.xz $dir");
```

you should have

```
system("tar $excludes -cJf $tmpbdir/$dir.xz $dir");
```

**EDIT**:

Remove the leading slash from excludes:

```
'home/webserver/ubuntubarsport/www/minecraft/*'
```

And if you don't need that directory itself also trailing slash and asterisk:

```
'home/webserver/ubuntubarsport/www/minecraft'
```

Keep in mind, that [tar](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar)'s --exclude expects pattern.

Comment: I have modified the script; now it does not return any error but there are all the files I excluded :\

Comment: Remove the leading slash in excludes

Answer (score 1):

Use the following modules in your Perl script instead of using your `system` call:

- Use [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to find the files you want to backup.
- Use [Archive::Tar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html) to create your tarball.

This removes the possible issues of system incompatibility, and you'll have more control over what you're backing up and where. Yes, it'll take a wee bit more elbow grease on your part. You'll have to learn these two modules, if you're not familiar with them, but both of these modules have been included in Perl since Perl 5.10. And, if you're using an older version of Perl, you can install them from CPAN.

In the end, you'll probably find this faster and more flexible. Plus, it's the *correct* way to handle the issue (i.e., use Perl modules instead of shelling out to operating system commands.

And, since you're now writing everything in pure Perl, you don't have the issue of how your `system` command interacts with the command line or what version of `tar` is on the computer.

File::Find is pretty simple (**NOTE**: Code not verified):

```
use File::Find;

my @dirList = qw(list of directories to go through);
my @file_list;

find ({
   push @file_list, $File::Find::name if -f; #Backup files only
}, @dirList);
```

This should put your files into `@file_list`. The subroutine in `find` can be used to filter out anything you don't want. And, you can use a reference to a subroutine too. The following is the same as above.

```
find (\&wanted, @dir_list);

sub wanted {
   if (-f) {   #Use the `if` to see whether you want to backup a file.
       push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
   }
}
```

I'm a bit more wobbly on `Archive::Tar`, but if I remember, it's a several step process:

- Use `my $object = Archive::Tar->new` to create an *object*.
- Use `$object->create_archive` to create a new tarball.
- Use `$object->add_files` to add the files you want in your tarball.
- When you finish, use `$object->write` to write the tarball to disk and close `$object`

Give it a try, it isn't too difficult, and you'll improve your Perl programming skills.